# Protected property became undefined

Tags: php, magento

This could be a Magento specific issue but so far it looks just weird from pure PHP perspective.

The error I see in the log file is:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote::$_serializableFields  in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php on line 753
```

Line 753 is:

```
foreach ($this->_serializableFields as $field => $parameters) {
```

The `_serializableFields` variable is defined in `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` as:

```
protected $_serializableFields   = array();
```

The `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote` class is a grandchild of `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` but there is nothing in it or its parent that would undefine the `_serializableFields` variable.

So the question is: how come the variable is undefined? Trying to find it out I logged the trace that leads to the error:

```
#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(422): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_serializeFields(Object(MageWorx_CustomPrice_Model_Sales_Quote))
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(MageWorx_CustomPrice_Model_Sales_Quote))
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1966): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php(380): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->save()
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php(357): Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create->initFromOrder(Object(MyCompany_Sales_Model_Order))
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController->reorderAction()
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reorder')
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#9 /app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#10 /index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#11 {main}
2014-03-27T04:25:22+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined property: Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote::$_serializableFields  in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php on line 753
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote` is extending your `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` class ?

Comment: Just copy-pasting class headers:
`class Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote extends Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Abstract

abstract class Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Abstract extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract

abstract class Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract`

Comment: This seams strange indeed. I've never experienced this. Check if there  is an extension interfering with the orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be APC on PHP 5.4 problem. Got rid of APC and it's all now fine. Installed Opcache instead.